# How to find an HTML element by what it contains using simpleHTMLdom?

Tags: html-parsing, simple-html-dom

what i need to do is parsing html with many tags without `id` or `class` and the website i want to parse contains pagination.

Here an example of the HTML part i want to get :

```
<tr>
    <th> number of pages </th>
    <td>
        <p> 160 </p> <==== just need the 160
    </td>
</tr>
```

First, i used `foreach($html->find('tr', 4)->find('td p') as $bookPages)`

But i've got error because : for page 1 the `<tr>` is in 4th position so i got a good result, but in other pages, it's in 3rd position or 5 (for example) because i can see some informations missing from page to page on the website i'm parsing.

Any way to perform something like :

```
foreach($html_book_page->find('th["the content of the th tag : number of pages"]') as $bookPages)
```

How to search an HTML element according to what it contains if no id or class and get the next tag (`td p` in my case)?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i<$data.find('tr').length; i++){

            info[i]=($($data).find('td').eq(i).find('p').text()).replace(/\n\r/g, '').trim();


        }
```

Try creating an array. The output should be the text from the `<p>` tag...i.e 160